# Create grid around points (centroids) using sf

Tags: r, grid, spatial, r-sf, centroid

I have EURO-CORDEX climate data which is on a 11 degrees rotated pole grid. I have pre-prepared this data by transforming the projection to WGS84. The data comes as points which represent the centroids of the square grid. I need to create the square grid that goes around these points. I have derived a general method for achieving this, but the final areas of the grid cells show errors of as much as 50%.

My code is below. I've been told off previously for providing code in tidyverse notation, so I have aimed to strip this out wherever possible. The data and code are on github here: https://github.com/avisserquinn/exampleData

*First I load in the longitude and latitude of my centroids from a csv and convert to a spatial feature data frame, with the WGS84 projection. These points should represent an 11 x 11 degree or 12 x 12 km grid.*

```
> library(tidyverse)
> library(sf)
> 
> data <- read_csv("stackExample.csv", col_types = cols())
> data <- st_as_sf(data, coords = c("lon", "lat")) # Spatial feature data frame
> data <- st_set_crs(data, 4326) # Set projection
> data
Simple feature collection with 2221 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -9.996 ymin: 50.051 xmax: 1.965 ymax: 61.938
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
# A tibble: 2,221 x 2
    grid        geometry
   <dbl>     <POINT [°]>
 1     1 (-9.996 51.768)
 2     2 (-9.979 53.544)
 3     3  (-9.96 52.013)
 4     4 (-9.931 51.666)
 5     5 (-9.924 52.258)
 6     6 (-9.912 53.442)
 7     7 (-9.906 54.034)
 8     8  (-9.895 51.91)
 9     9 (-9.875 53.687)
10    10 (-9.869 54.278)
# ... with 2,211 more rows
> 
> ggplot(data) + geom_sf() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

*I create the grid by applying st_make_grid twice (from the sf spatial features package). The first time, I find the centers between the points. The second time, I find the grid corners, such that the points are now centroids.*

```
> cellsize = .11 
> dataGrid <- st_make_grid(data, cellsize = cellsize, what = "centers") 
> dataGrid <- st_make_grid(dataGrid, cellsize = cellsize)
> dataGrid <- dataGrid %>% as_tibble %>% st_as_sf
> dataGrid

Simple feature collection with 11772 features and 0 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -9.941 ymin: 50.106 xmax: 1.939 ymax: 62.096
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
First 10 features:
                         geometry
1  POLYGON ((-9.941 50.106, -9...
2  POLYGON ((-9.831 50.106, -9...
3  POLYGON ((-9.721 50.106, -9...
4  POLYGON ((-9.611 50.106, -9...
5  POLYGON ((-9.501 50.106, -9...
6  POLYGON ((-9.391 50.106, -9...
7  POLYGON ((-9.281 50.106, -9...
8  POLYGON ((-9.171 50.106, -9...
9  POLYGON ((-9.061 50.106, -8...
10 POLYGON ((-8.951 50.106, -8...
```

*Next, I aggregate this gridded data with the centroids, to find only the matching grid cells.*

```
> dataGrid <- aggregate(data, dataGrid, FUN = mean)
> dataGrid <- as_tibble(dataGrid)
> dataGrid <- dataGrid[!is.na(dataGrid$grid),]
> dataGrid$area_sqm = st_area(dataGrid$geometry)
> dataGrid$area_sqkm = as.numeric(unlist(dataGrid$area_sqm * 10^-6))
> dataGrid$area_deficit = (12*12) - dataGrid$area_sqkm
> dataGrid
# A tibble: 2,175 x 5
    grid                                                                      geometry area_sqm area_sqkm area_deficit
   <dbl>                                                                 <POLYGON [°]>    [m^2]     <dbl>        <dbl>
 1  656  ((-5.651 50.106, -5.541 50.106, -5.541 50.216, -5.651 50.216, -5.651 50.106)) 96173304      96.2         47.8
 2  678  ((-5.431 50.106, -5.321 50.106, -5.321 50.216, -5.431 50.216, -5.431 50.106)) 96173304      96.2         47.8
 3  702  ((-5.211 50.106, -5.101 50.106, -5.101 50.216, -5.211 50.216, -5.211 50.106)) 96173304      96.2         47.8
 4  730  ((-5.101 50.106, -4.991 50.106, -4.991 50.216, -5.101 50.216, -5.101 50.106)) 96173304      96.2         47.8
 5  693  ((-5.321 50.216, -5.211 50.216, -5.211 50.326, -5.321 50.326, -5.321 50.216)) 95954257      96.0         48.0
 6  720  ((-5.101 50.216, -4.991 50.216, -4.991 50.326, -5.101 50.326, -5.101 50.216)) 95954257      96.0         48.0
 7  762  ((-4.881 50.216, -4.771 50.216, -4.771 50.326, -4.881 50.326, -4.881 50.216)) 95954257      96.0         48.0
 8 1044  ((-3.891 50.216, -3.781 50.216, -3.781 50.326, -3.891 50.326, -3.891 50.216)) 95954257      96.0         48.0
 9  712  ((-5.211 50.326, -5.101 50.326, -5.101 50.436, -5.211 50.436, -5.211 50.326)) 95734844      95.7         48.3
10  746. ((-4.991 50.326, -4.881 50.326, -4.881 50.436, -4.991 50.436, -4.991 50.326)) 95734844      95.7         48.3
# ... with 2,165 more rows
```

*When I plot the final output you can see the problem. The grid cell sizes are off by a significant amount (the deficit); I expect some deviation from the 12 x 12 km as the projection is curved, but this level of deficit is extreme. In addition, there are gaps in the grid; I am presuming that this is because the incorrect size of the grid cells means that not all points are captured?*

```
> ggplot(dataGrid) + 
+   geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry, fill = area_deficit)) +
+   theme_minimal() +  
+   scale_fill_viridis_c(direction = -1) +
+   scale_colour_viridis_c(direction = -1) +
+   coord_sf()
```

[image]

I've tried a number of options to try to fix this without success. Any advice on alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`st_make_grid()` just uses the bounding box of the first argument, so you could just extend the bounding box by 1/2 of the cell size in each direction:

```
# Generate some centroids
centroids <- st_make_grid(what="centers") %>% st_sf()

# Make a new grid from them
cellSize <- 10
grid <- (st_bbox(centroids) + cellSize/2*c(-1,-1,1,1)) %>%
  st_make_grid(cellsize=c(cellSize, cellSize)) %>% st_sf()

ggplot() + geom_sf(data=grid) + geom_sf(data=centroids)
```

[Example grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVriM.png)

This post is pretty old at this point so the link is broken, but a cell size of .11 doesn't look correct. Hopefully you worked it out.