# Creating spatial grid from list of centroids using R

Tags: r, grid, spatial, r-sf, centroid

I have a list of coordinates (lat, lon) and would like to create  a grid of squares where each of these coordinates is in the center of the square using R, and preferably SF (as I am used to it), but also open for other suggestions.

I basically trying to construct a grid of squares (that touches each other) around the points in the attached map.

This is first 5 obs of my data (the entire dataset spread across all Africa - like in the attached picture in the link):

```
Bounding box:  xmin: 18.25 ymin: -34.75 xmax: 20.25 ymax: -34.25
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
   cell             geometry
1     1 POINT (19.75 -34.75)
15    2 POINT (20.25 -34.75)
29    3 POINT (18.25 -34.25)
43    4 POINT (18.75 -34.25)
57    5 POINT (19.25 -34.25)
71    6 POINT (19.75 -34.25)
```

and would like to make a grid style st_make_grid(cellsize = XXX, what = "polygons") where the geometris points above are in the center of each polygon.

[image]

Comment: This would be a much better question if you provided a small amount of sample data to illustrate. For illustration purposes a 2x2 or a 3x3 grid is probably sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I updated my post! Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that your points are evenly spaced? Is the map you included a map of the points, or of what you're trying to obtain? If you just want to use your points as grid centers, try `st_make_grid(x, what = "centers")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create grid around points (centroids) using sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58800327/create-grid-around-points-centroids-using-sf)